# Implement delete button on each table row using model binding and POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

On my view, I have a table with a form that I want to use to delete a particular row. I use a foreach loop to generate an hidden input field with the row value that I want to pass to the controller and `asp-for` tag for model biding, and a submit button.

The value that is passed to the controller is always the first row. I'm inclined to think that the reason for this behavior is that the generated input fields all have the same name attribute, because the `asp-for` expression is invariant for every iteration of the foreach loop.

Is there a straight-forward way to implement this using a form and a POST request, or should I just use anchors with route values, i.e., GET requests?

**Here's my ViewModel:**

```
public class RolesViewModel
}
    public IList<AppUser> UsersInRole {get; set;}
    public string SelectedRole {get; set;}
    public RemoveUserFromRole RemoveUser {get; set;}

    public class RemoveUserFromRole 
    {
        public string UserName {get; set;}
        public string RoleName {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
<form method="post" asp-action="RemoveUser" id="removeUserForm"></form>
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var user in Model.UsersInRole)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.UserName</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <input form="removeUserForm" asp-for="RemoveUser.UserName" type="hidden" value="@user.UserName" />
                <input form="removeUserForm" asp-for="RemoveUser.RoleName" type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedRoleName" />
                <button form="removeUserForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-danger py-0 my-0">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**And my action method in controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUser(RolesViewModel model)
{
    //model.RemoveUser.UserName always have the value from the first row
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.RemoveUser.UserName);
    if (user == null)
        return RolesError(await GetModel());

    var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, model.RemoveUser.RoleName);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
        return RolesError(await GetModel());


    return RedirectToAction("Roles", new { roleName = model.RemoveUser.RoleName });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was capable of solving this issue with minimal code footprint.

As it turns out, `<td>` tags can have forms, so, knowing that, it is possible to have a different form on each row, like so:

**View:**

```
//Remove inline table form
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var user in Model.UsersInRole)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.UserName</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                //now each form will have the correct, row-wise formdata
                <form method="post" asp-action="RemoveUser">
                    <input asp-for="RemoveUser.UserName" type="hidden" value="@user.UserName" />
                    <input asp-for="RemoveUser.RoleName" type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedRoleName" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-danger py-0 my-0">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your codes, I found you have multiple hidden filed which contains the `user.UserName`.

If you click the submit button, it will upload all the hidden filed value to the code-behind and it will just bind the first one, this is the reason why your model is always first one.

You could find the formdata in F12 developtool's network.

[image]

To solve this issue, we have a easily but not a good solution.

We could set mutiple form tag in your table to avoid post all the all the hidden filed username value to controller:

Like below:

```
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

         @foreach (var user in Model.UsersInRole)
         { int i = 0;



            <tr>

                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                <td class="text-center">
        <form method="post" asp-action="RemoveUser" id="@user.UserName">

                    <input form="@user.UserName" name="RemoveUser.UserName" type="hidden" value="@user.UserName" />
                    <input form="@user.UserName" name="RemoveUser.RoleName" type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedRole" />
                    <button form="@user.UserName" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-danger py-0 my-0">
                        <i class="fas fa-times">iiiii</i>
                    </button>
        </form>
                </td>

            </tr>

                }
    
        </tbody>
</table>
```

If you choose this way, you should rebuild all your view's html makeup.

Besides, you could try to use ajax to achieve your requirement, this solution is better than before solution. You could use jquery to get the right form data according to the submit button's id or position and then use jquery ajax to post the form data into controller. Then you could return the redirect url instead of `RedirectToAction` methods.

More details about how to use ajax to send form data, you could refer to below codes:

```
@model MVCRelatedIssue.Models.RolesViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<form method="post" asp-action="RemoveUser" id="removeUserForm">

    <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">User name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var user in Model.UsersInRole)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>@user.UserName</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <input form="removeUserForm" name="RemoveUser.UserName" type="hidden" value="@user.UserName" />
                        <input form="removeUserForm" name="RemoveUser.RoleName" type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedRole" />
                        <button form="removeUserForm" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-danger py-0 my-0 subbtn">
                            <i class="fas fa-times">iiiii</i>
                        </button>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".subbtn").bind("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formdata = new FormData();
                var UserName = $(this).prev().prev().val();
                formdata.append("RemoveUser.UserName", UserName);
                console.log(UserName);
                var roleName = $(this).prev().val();
                formdata.append("RemoveUser.RoleName", roleName);
                console.log(roleName);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/RemoveUser/RemoveUser",
                    data: formdata,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
        
                        window.location.href = data;
                    }
                });

             });
        }); 
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUser(RolesViewModel model)
    {
        //model.RemoveUser.UserName always have the value from the first row
        //var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.RemoveUser.UserName);
        //if (user == null)
        //    return RolesError(await GetModel());

        //var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, model.RemoveUser.RoleName);
        //if (!result.Succeeded)
        //    return RolesError(await GetModel());

         string redirecturl = "/RemoveUser/Roles?roleName=" + model.RemoveUser.RoleName;

        return Ok(redirecturl);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was trying your first solution and I discovered that it is possible to have a separate form on each row. Please check my answer.

Comment: Since I don't know what your actually requirement, I just give you a way. By using my first solution, you should make sure you just want 2 formdata to send back to the controller.  If you want to send another formdata you need change your html makeup. If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer. So that other folks could find the workable answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Delete Link
in View

```
@foreach (var user in Model.UsersInRole)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("RemoveUser", "YOUR_Controller",new {username = user.UserName})"
                       onclick="return confirm('Do You want to Delete');" 
                    </a>
}
```

In Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUser(String username)
{
    // Get the user Object the delete it
}
```